# SQL CE Insert Statement with Vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, sql-server-ce

I have the following code in wpf with vb.net and sql CE 3.5, and my OS is win7 64bit.  Visual studios is 2010.  I imported the following:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe
Imports System.Data
```

The main part of the code is:

```
            Dim Con As SqlCeConnection = New SqlCeConnection(DataSource)
            Dim Cmd As SqlCeCommand
            If Con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then Con.Open()

            'Inserting Prime Details
            Try
                Cmd = New SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO [ContactPrime]([ID],[Namee],[Company],[JobTitle],[Number],[Address],[Typee] VALUES (@ID,@Namee,@Company,@JobTitle,@Number,@Address,@Typee)", Con)
                With InsertObject.Prime
                    Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = .ID
                    Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@Namee", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = .Namee
                    Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@Company", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = .Company
                    Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@JobTitle", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = .JobTitle
                    Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@Number", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = .Number
                    Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = .Address
                    Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@Typee", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = .Typee
                End With
                Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try


            'Inserting  Numbers of Contact
            Try
                For Each num In InsertObject.Numbers
                    Cmd = New SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO [ContactNumbers]([ContactID],[ID],[Title],[Mobile],[Land],[Fax],[Email],[IsPrimary] VALUES (@ContactID,@ID,@Title,@Mobile,@Land,@Fax,@Email,@IsPrimary)", Con)
                    With num
                        Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@ContactID", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = .ContactID
                        Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = .ID
                        Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = .Title
                        Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@Mobile", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = .Mobile
                        Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@Land", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = .Land
                        Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@Fax", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = .Fax
                        Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = .Email
                        Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@IsPrimary", SqlDbType.Bit)).Value = .IsPrimary
                    End With
                    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
```

The error I get is:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
```

Could you please tell me where I have done wrong.  The connection works perfectly, I test with a select statement and it worked, it seems my insert statement is wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, you are not closing the bracket before VALUES starts...

```
"INSERT INTO [ContactNumbers]([ContactID],[ID],[Title],[Mobile],[Land],
 [Fax],[Email],[IsPrimary] 
 VALUES (@ContactID,@ID,@Title,@Mobile,@Land,@Fax,@Email,@IsPrimary)
```

You are missing the closing bracket in above statement so corrected query will be like this:

```
"INSERT INTO [ContactNumbers]([ContactID],[ID],[Title],[Mobile],[Land],
 [Fax],[Email],[IsPrimary])
 VALUES (@ContactID,@ID,@Title,@Mobile,@Land,@Fax,@Email,@IsPrimary)
```

Similary, same thing happens in second `INSERT` query too....

Comment: Hahaha, Thank you that works, it seems I need to go to eye doctor sometime soon.